# Intellij IDEA SDK - How can I programmatically handle spellcheck 'typos'?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Wrote a plugin to handle some custom format stuff in yaml files that I've written for a huge project. It's a chat bot that can respond in a huge number of ways. There is a lot of slang and non-standard words in the yaml.

I don't want to disable spellchecking as I want to fix legitimate speeling errors. But the annotations under the "misspelled" slang words are conflicting with the annotations in my plugin, and causing issue.

One yaml file has 349 "typos". 10% or so are legit. The rest are slang and custom words.

I need to do one of two things. Either add those words to the dictionary (I've found the method to do that - SpellCheckManager.getInstance(project).acceptWordAsCorrect()) OR get a list of the words and create a custom dictionary from them. Both approaches require me to grab a list of all typos in the document/editor/project.

That's the part I can't find. Looked everywhere. (List of current Annotations? List of current Problems?) Googled my fingers off. Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'd recommend you raise this issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development to discuss it with the IDEA team directly.

Comment: My experience there has been abysmally slow responses. Thought I'd ask here first, but, you're probably right. Was worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the IDEAL solution, but it worked for my means, and I'm leaving the answer in case this is googled.

In DaemonCodeAnalyzerImpl, there is a method:

```
DaemonCodeAnalyzerImpl.getHighlights(Document document, HighlightSeverity minSeverity, Project project);
```

This returns a list of all highlights in the document. The method is Annotated with @TestOnly, and docs state that it should only be used in Test code because it breaks/shortcuts the normal way to access that. It still works in non-test code however.

Since the only thing I wanted was the strings of the typos, I pulled the list, then looped through the HighlightInfo's in the list, and pulled the .getText()s.

No danger of screwing anything up.

Then pushed all those strings into:

```
SpellCheckerManager.getInstance(project).acceptWordAsCorrect(word, project);
```

Viola! All current highlighted typos are now added to the dictionary.

*Proper* solution? No. Good enough for what I needed to accomplish? Yup.